# does matlab have a built in function for discrete signal addition?

Tags: matlab

does matlab have a built in function for discrete signal addition?

can only find google of scripts, no built in function

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete"?  Finite fields? (lookfor galois or gf). Obviously vectors represent sampled *discrete time* signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean add signal a and signal b together? If so its just:

> > a + b % assumes both are of same length. Zero pad if not

or are you refering to discrete convolution or something?

Comment: The zero padding statement is incorrect. If a and b are not the same length and one isn't a scalar, it will throw an error.

Comment: @gnovice I think his comment is a note to the user that they need to pad it with 0's, not a statement that it will automatically do it.